# Are there any rules for genitive case not indicating possesion?

Tags: grammar, possessives, rules, attributive-nouns, possessive-s-vs-of

My teacher, a native English speaker, was quite puzzled when I asked this and could not answer this question.

Why there is:

> child seat  but children's love  //why these are different
>
> developer's conference   //why not developers conference, they do not own it
>
> rooms' furnishings

The question is, how to tell when to use the genitive and when simple noun?

Comment: Why would you think “ownership” has anything to do with this matter?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/50740

Comment: tchrist: because it looks like that because of the 's'. The thing is when to use 's' and when just a noun...

Comment: tchrist: The question you referred to is about a different topic. I do not discuss the order of words or usage of nouns but the genitive case only.

Comment: "Child seat" does not belong to a child.  "Child" is used as a descriptor for the seat.  I would say "developer conference" is also appropriate, if not more, where "developer" is the type of conference.  Same for "room furnishings."  Using the possessive is possible too in some cases; in "children's love" it's straightforward because the love belongs to the children.

Comment: A "learner question"' -- please ask on [ell.se]

Comment: This reminds me of [*users’s guide* vs *user’s guide* vs *user guide* vs *users guide*](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/36657). It also seems to be asking when it is ok to use an apostrophe-s for an inanimate agent, like [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30385) touches upon.